# Where does windows error reporting create the dump file

Tags: windows, windbg, windows-error-reporting

I just want to find out which location does the WER write its dump file? Also is this location specific to OS?

Comment: What is the purpose for? If it is for getting back information MSFT provides a mechanism located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487440

Comment: my app keep crashing, i couldn't find much info from dump file i generated from adplus. Just curious if WER dump file has any other info

Comment: Are you able to debug and see what exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: Like I said i couldn't find much info from that dump file.

Comment: Not through the dump file but like visual studio and run your code. Are you able to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation for WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you can set registry setting to control the dump location and the type of dump

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpFolder
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpType

Default value for DumpFolder is %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps.

Comment: In windows 10, it appears the directory is `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive`, but no directory related key exists within the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting` branch

Comment: there are relevant entries at `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Problem Reports` and `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance` under the top entry of the `Maintenance` heading